# itemize in vwcol environment (using beamer slides) disfunctional

Tags: beamer

I have realized that the vwcol environment (used to specify the size of the individual columns) does not work if you put an itemize inside. The following MWE proves this: only the first usage of vwvol works (here, text ist used within), but the second doesn't.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{vwcol}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{vwcol}[widths={.5,.5}]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus
elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur
dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget,
consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu
neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et
malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra
\end{vwcol}


\begin{vwcol}[widths={.5,.5}]
\begin{itemize}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\item 4
\item 5
\item 6
\end{itemize}
\end{vwcol}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

It seems like the size of the first column is as large as the whole slide as soon as one uses as list:

[image]

Any ideas whether and how this can be fixed?

Comment: Beamer has its own mechanism for creating columns: `\begin{columns}\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth} ... \end{column}\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth} ... \end{column}\end{columns}`.

Comment: You are right, that works! Thank you. Wouldn't you like to turn your comment into a real answer? I'll mark it as answer, then.

Comment: I already did... but you may wait, maybe someone who has a real solution will show up and give you a real answer, not just a workaround.

Comment: Sorry, I was quicker again. :) And in case another answer fixes the problem that causes vwcol to not work correctly here, I will be happy to mark that as answer.

Comment: Usually answerers do not ask not to accept your answer, but if you accept mine before giving other a chance to read your question, this may lead to a situation in which others just see that this question has already an accepted answer and thus not even read it.

Comment: Yes, I see your point. Here, however, I believe that my question was actually sufficiently answered, although I still don't know the technical cause of the problem. I see it that way: if anyone else is dissatisfied with your answer, then they might just state so in the comments; maybe I'll uncheck it then. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I have never heard of the `vwcol` package before. All I can do is to provide you with a workaround: use beamer's own mechanism for creating columns.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{vwcol}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\begin{vwcol}[widths={.5,.5}]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus
elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur
dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget,
consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu
neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et
malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra
\end{vwcol}

\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth} 
\begin{itemize}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth} 
\begin{itemize}
\item 4
\item 5
\item 6
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

vwcol package is for columns of different widths. As I can see, your column widths are set to {.5,.5}, so are not of different widths. You don't need vwcol package. Use multicols package that works perfectly.